# Measure the amount of time a celery message is on the queue

Tags: python, celery

Is there a good way to measure the amount of time a celery message spends on the queue? I know I could send a timestamp to the celery task and measure the difference between the beginning of the task and the timestamp sent, but I was hoping there might be a more general way to do it so I don't have to add timestamps to every single one of my celery tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to checkout **Celery Flower**, it's a very extensive reports for the broker, queues, tasks. And it's so easy to run (Just a couple of commands).

Here you go http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor